# Guarantee creation order in DynamoDB?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to have my items automatically ordered by creation order in DynamoDB?

I've tried using an ISO timestamp in my sort-keys but I soon noticed that items created in the same second have no guaranteed order.

Another major issue is that my sort-key is composite, for example :

```
Sort_Key : someRandomUuidHere|Created:someTimeStampHere
```

I need to generate UUIds to try to guarantee it is unique, but adding the timestamp at the end of the uuid doesn't seem to order it by the timestamp, but by the uuid instead. And if I add the timestamp to the start I can't use things like begins_with so it breaks my access patterns

The only way I could think of was maintaining a "last-key" object and always ask it the last item index before, but that would require an extra request and some ACID logic.

Or maybe just order it on the client side, there's always that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort keys are sorted left to right...so yeah, the UUID would be the only component that affects the order.

Why not place the timestamp first?

Alternatively, consider just Time-Based UUID. Dynamo doesn't offer one natively, alothough some NoSQL DB's, such as Cassandra, do.

Here's an article that discusses creating one with .NET
[Creating a Time UUID (GUID) in .NET](http://nickberardi.com/creating-a-time-uuid-guid-in-net/)

Which includes a link the following source 
https://github.com/fluentcassandra/fluentcassandra/blob/master/src/GuidGenerator.cs

Comment: I guess I could just have an ID that is the concatenation of the Timestamp with an UUID, although that will get somewhat large. And AFAIK UUIDs are already time based, just not in order.